# Can a site like this be designed in full html and css?

Tags: html, css, image

Currently the one shown is designed in html and images. Just wondering if it can be done before I can start including the center piece where it splits and turns. Doesnt have to be responsive but just be full width. I dont want to start and then be stuck where in the middle it does a split

[image]

Comment: For us to help you, you'll need to at least attempt to do this. It's unclear as to what you're looking to do.

Comment: What im trying to ask is can one create a site layout like this in FULL html and css code? I did one in 50% html and 50% images. Just wondering if it can be done in 100% code

Comment: If you're talking about the "cut corner", you can get pretty close with regular css "border-radius" property. That gives you a rounded corner though, but it's the simplest, most straight forward way without resorting to javascript or SVG or other drawing exercises.

Comment: Short answer is yes. If you want it to be completely with CSS, you can "fake" the border corners by using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements and absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible in lot of ways: here is one way I created on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/PvNbZq)

Here is that HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.block img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -65px;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.left img {
  right: 15px;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Site</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```